# Como preencher espaços null de um array java?

Tags: java, array, java-8

Eu preciso armazenar o primeiro e último nome de uma pessoa dentro de uma variável.

Consegui separar as palavras da String dentro de um array
e pegar o primeiro nome (pelo índice 0) - e agora gostaria de saber como pegar o último nome.

```
        String nomeCompleto; //variável para pegar o nome completo
        System.out.println("Digite o nome ");
        nomeCompleto = sc.nextLine(); //lendo nome

        //separando o nome completo em nomes separados para obter o primeiro e último nome
        String nome = nomeCompleto; 
        String arrayNome[] = new String[5];
        arrayNome = nome.split(" ");

        for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
            System.out.println(arrayNome[c]);
        } //mostrando os valores dentro do array
```

O programa está lendo todos os valores, porém, ao chegar em um índice que não existe valor, o programa dá erro - acredito que isto ocorre por ser `null`.

Comment: `c < 5` - quem garante que o array sempre terá 5 elementos? Se tiver mais, vc estará ignorando os restantes, se tiver menos, dará erro de index out of bound (ou seja, nada a ver com `null`). Use `c < arrayNome.length` que garante que sempre percorrerá todos, independente da quantidade.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Não fixe o valor do nome em 5 pois nem todo nome terá este tamanho, por exemplo "André Luiz Santos" teria o tamanho de 3 apenas.

Já que está trabalhando com array basta pegar o ultimo elemento que é o tamanho do array -1. Se tamanho igual a 3 o índice do ultimo elemento do array será 2.

Outro ponto a considerar é que o array pode estar vazio e neste caso neste caso o tamanho do array gerado seria 0 e o ultimo elemento neste modelo procuraria 0 - 1 e também dá erro, então recomendo procurar o ultimo nome somente se o tamanho do arrayNome for maior que 1.

Tente desta forma

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nomeCompleto; //variável para pegar o nome completo
    System.out.println("Digite o nome ");
    nomeCompleto = sc.nextLine(); //lendo nome

    //separando o nome completo em nomes separados para obter o primeiro e último nome
    String nome = nomeCompleto;
    //Linha removida pois nem todo nome tem é composto por 5 nomes
    // String arrayNome[] = new String[5];

    //inicia a array com o tamanho adequado para cada nome
    String[] arrayNome = nome.split(" ");

    if(arrayNome.length > 1) {
        String ultimoNome = arrayNome[arrayNome.length - 1]; //Ultimo elemento do array
        System.out.println("O ultimo nome é " + ultimoNome);
    }
}
```